# How do I find a specific table with watir-webdriver

Tags: ruby, webdriver, watir-webdriver

I'm fairly new to Ruby and web testing in general. My company already has most of their automation in watir and I'm currently switching it over to watir-webdriver. The documentation isn't so hot so I'm making it up as I go. I'm having difficulty finding a specific table. The only way that I can identify if a table exists right now is to simply look for table headers and cells, like so:

```
b.th(:text=>"Blah").exists?
b.td(:text=>"Hrrrgg").exists?
```

I don't know how to get the table itself into a variable and then manipulate its headerss, rows, sections, etc.

Actually, I have one way that I thought of while writing this but it doesn't look so hot. I could do

```
#(header->row->section->table)
b.th(:text=>"Blah).parent.parent.parent
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
b.tables.find{|table| table.th(:text=>"Blah").exists?}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look for the table similar to how you are doing the table headers and cells, but use `.table` instead.

For example, you can do:

```
b.table(:id, 'tables_id').exists?   #=> Finds table with id 'tables_id'
b.table(:index, 0).exists?          #=> Finds first table
```

You can get a list of elements and locators for the original Watir [here](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/HTML+Elements+Supported+by+Watir). Watir-Webdriver should be pretty much the same. But you can always double-check the API docs [here](http://rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/frames).

Comment: Yeah this would be my ideal answer but my tables have absolutely no identifiers on them. It's silly. I could perhaps use index but I'm not too comfortable with that.

Comment: @stack1, maybe you are looking for `browser.tables.each`? if not, I would suggest opening a new question that includes the HTML you are working with and the exact problem.